# function on $(document).ready not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tring to load an html on a div when the page load with jquery load method but it's not working and i get this error from the firebug console

> "ReferenceError: dialog_forms is not defined".

I thnk jquery file is corectly loaded but nothing it's loaded on the "editor-place" div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://localhost/esi3d/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src="http://localhost/esi3d/js/action.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/themes/flexigrid/css/flexigrid.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/css/jquery_plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/css/ui/simple/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css" />

    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/jquery.noty.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/config/jquery.noty.config.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/js/common/lazyload-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/js/common/list.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/themes/flexigrid/js/cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/themes/flexigrid/js/flexigrid.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/jquery.numeric.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/themes/flexigrid/js/jquery.printElement.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/esi3d/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>

<style type='text/css'>
body
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
a {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>

<script>
function funcion_javascript(){
   alert ("Esto es javascript");
}
</script> 
</head><body>
<!-- Beginning header -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href=http://localhost/esi3d/index.php/clase>Clases</a></li>
                <li><a href=http://localhost/esi3d/index.php/office>Despachos</a></li>
                <li><a href=http://localhost/esi3d/index.php/dependency>Otras dependencias</a></li>
                <li><a href=http://localhost/esi3d/index.php/extra>Extras</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href=http://localhost/esi3d/index.php/editor>Editor</a></li>
                <li><a href=http://localhost/esi3d/index.php/user_admin>Administracion de usuario</a></li>
                <!--<li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" onclick="go('user_admin/logout')">Cerrar sesión</button><li>-->
                <li>
                    <p class="navbar-btn">
                        <a href="http://localhost/esi3d/index.php/user_admin/logout"  class="btn btn-default" role="button">Cerrar sesión</a>
                     </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
<!-- End of header-->

    <div id="editor-place">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#editor-place" ).load( 'http://localhost/esi3d/application/editor/editor.html');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The way u  trying to reference javascript and css files doesn't look's the correct way, you can avoid the local host portion and add a relative path.

Comment: actually thisis the generated code, on the php file it's like ` <link href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: what are the contents of `http://localhost/esi3d/application/editor/editor.html`?

Comment: Check your browsers console for any 401/404 errors when loading your SRC content in the head. Maybe something is not loading and that is why JQuery is failing to execute.

Comment: it's a unity web application

Comment: are u getting any errors in the console?

Comment: "ReferenceError: dialog_forms is not defined".

Comment: In your HTML, I do not see an ID of `dialog_forms`, so whatever is calling it is complaining.

Comment: Also you're loading JQuery 1.11.2 from Google and then JQuery 1.11.1 locally, this can be a really bad idea. Pick one to use.

Comment: Comment out the non-essential scripts to make sure that you can simply load that file into the #editor-place div. Then you can try to determine which is throwing that error.

Comment: `bootstrap.js` will definitely break because you load another `jQuery.js` after it ... get rid of second version of jQuery.js

Answer (score 0):

"dialog_forms" is a jQuery UI dialog?
you're initializing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#editor-place" ).dialog();
    $( "#editor-place" ).load( 'http://localhost/esi3d/application/editor/editor.html');
    $( "#editor-place" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I dont know what is dialog_form it's not created for me

Comment: I think, the data (in the load) execute a javascript, and these open the dialog, but isn't init. So... 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $( "#editor-place" ).load( 'http://localhost/esi3d/application/editor/editor.html', function()
        {
            $( "#dialog_forms" ).dialog();
            $( "#dialog_forms" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Check the Console, could be a CROSS restriction.
If the content is in a local page change the "localhost" by a relative address;

```
$( "#editor-place" ).load( '../editor/editor.html');
```